# Javascript Hide Element by ID Based on Browser

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am trying to show a message to all browsers and remove it though javascript if it is supported. Currently the only way it will be hidden is if I click a hide button. It won't *run* in my if statement.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
var browser=navigator.appCodeName + navigator.appName;
function hideStuff(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
 }

function supportedBrowser() {
if (browser == "MozillaNetscape")
  {
  document.write("Browser is Mozilla Netscape");
  }
else if (browser == "MozillaOpera")
  {
  document.write("Browser is Mozilla Opera");
  hideStuff('browserMessage');
  }
else
  {
alert("Please upgrade your browser.");
 }
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="hideStuff('browserMessage'); return false;">Hide</a>
<br><br>
<p id="browserMessage" style="display: inline;">Please use a supported browser.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Changed as according to "bluevoodoo1"

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
var browser=navigator.appCodeName + navigator.appName;
function hideStuff(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
function supportedBrowser() {
if (browser == "MozillaNetscape")
  {
  document.write("Browser is Mozilla Netscape");
  }
else if (browser == "MozillaOpera")
  {
  document.write("Browser is Mozilla Opera");
  //hideStuff('browserMessage');
  }
else
  {
alert("Please upgrade your browser.");
    }
}
function init() {
         supportedBrowser();
       //etc
    }
    window.onload = supportedBrowser;
    //-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="hideStuff('browserMessage'); return false;">Hide</a>
<br><br>
<p id="browserMessage" style="display: inline;">Please use a supported browser.</p>
<p>This text shoudld not be hidden.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you want the result to look like when the page loads? Do you want the message to write to the `browserMessage` element? Should it overwrite the message that is currently there?

Comment: I want the message to be displayed for all browsers except the supported ones. What I want javascript to do is toggle the visibility of this message, if the browser is supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might need use the window.onload handler... (jquery's "document.ready" is probably preferred, but I'm using some native javascript below)

```
<script>
    function init() {
         supportedBrowser();
         //etc
    }
    window.onload = init; 
</script>
```

Comment: Now only the text written by javascript will be displayed. Commenting the "window.onload" line will cause it to display properly. I will post my updated code.

Comment: `document.write` has a lovely tendency to blank out the entire existing document when called after the DOM is loaded.  That's probably what you're seeing.  Seeing as it looks as if your `document.write`s might be mostly for debugging anyway, try removing them.  Otherwise replace them with `alert` or better, `console.log` (Firebug, Webkit console, IE8 dev tools console, etc.)